# why shows Unresolved reference: putFile when using putFile for upload a image to the firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, file-upload

when I use `putFile()` its showing:

```
Unresolved reference: putFile
```

[image]

I tried to upload a image to firebase

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. please copy your code text instead of screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to call putFile() method on the DatabaseReference instance, which doesn't have this method. I guess, what you are intented to do is to put image into Firebase storage. To do that, change your:

```
val storageReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("HotelImages/$fileName")
```

to:

```
val storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("HotelImages/$fileName")
```

But, this will work only asserting that you configured your firebase storage properly. In order to do that, you have to configure storage inside your Firebase console and add specific storage dependency into your gradle module dependencies.